# Use RMAN to perform an incremental backup strategy

Tags: oracle, backup, oracle-10g, rman

the question is

Use RMAN to perform an incremental backup strategy (level = 0.1 and 1 cumulative) of the data files belonging to the SYSTEM and USERS tablespaces. Be sure to also make a copy of the current control file and server settings file. The backups must be placed in the C: \ DONTTOUCH \ directory and must use the df_% d_% s_% p.bak format for file names and must use two channels in parallel automatically

how i can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
configure controlfile autobackup on;
configure controlfile autobackup format for device type disk to 'C:\DONTTOUCH\%F';
```

This takes care of:

> Be sure to also make a copy of the current control file and server
>   settings file.

Next:

```
configure channel device type disk format 'C:\DONTTOUCH\df_% d_% s_% p.bak';
configure device type disk parallelism 2;
configure default device type disk;
```

This takes care of:

> The backups must be placed in the C: \ DONTTOUCH \ directory and must
>   use the df_% d_% s_% p.bak format for file names and must use two
>   channels in parallel automatically

Running the incremental level 0 backup:

```
backup incremental level 0 tablespace system, users;
```

Running the incremental level 1 backup:

```
backup incremental level 1 cumulative tablespace system, users;
```

Note: UNDO tablespace should be backed up as well, without that, the usefulness of these backups is quite limited.

Comment: Is it possible to put all this in a block RUN{ ... }

Comment: "Is it possible to put all this in a block RUN{ ... } "    What happens when you try?  Don't be afraid to discover things with your own testing.

Comment: The only advantages I see in this instance in putting it in a `run` block is that the `configure` commands would only apply to the group of commands within the `run` block.

Comment: @MarkStewart No, that is `SET`, not `CONFIGURE`. You can not set options such as default device type with `SET`. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/backup.112/e10643/rcmcomma005.htm `CONFIGURE` - Configure persistent RMAN settings. These settings apply to all RMAN sessions until explicitly changed or disabled. `SET` - Set the value of various attributes that affect RMAN behavior for the duration of a RUN block or a session.

Comment: @Balazs Papp You are right; I just tested that and found that out!  Thanks for noting that.